# Randomly selecting elements from a set in Python

Tags: python, random

If I have a set like so:

```
s = set(range(1,100))
```

How might I randomly generate a subset of `s` containing `k` distinct elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random
random.sample(s, k)
```

Comment: Note, if you can manage it, avoid passing `set` to `random.sample`.  If I'm reading the source properly, it executes `random.sample(tuple(s), k)` -- at least for sets with length greater than 21.

Comment: Good point. There is no need to call `set()` on the `range` object.

Comment: `X = {1,2,3,4}; random.sample(X, 1)` DeprecationWarning: Sampling from a set deprecated since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.sample) module:

```
>>> random.sample(s,  10) 
[14, 43, 42, 18, 80, 63, 15, 59, 49, 57]
```

There is no need for you to `s=set(range(100))` as `range` will provide a list of numbers in ascending order from 0 to 99.So, all of them are unique.

Just feed that `range(1,100)` to the `random.sample` method:

```
>>> random.sample(range(1,100), k)
```

Quoting from [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.sample):

> `random.sample(population, k)` Return a k length list of **unique elements**
>   chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling
>   without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) from the `random` module.

```
import random
items = set(range(1, 100))
selection = set(random.sample(items, 10))
```